Issues Installing CUDA and cuDNN on Ubuntu 24.04
I'm currently using Ubuntu 24.04 and have encountered several issues while trying to install CUDA and cuDNN drivers. Despite following the installation instructions, I am running into problems. Additionally, after the installation, my external monitor is no longer being detected.
Below is my nvdia default installed driver.

 +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| NVIDIA-SMI 535.183.01 Driver Version: 535.183.01 CUDA Version: 12.2 |

|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

| GPU Name Persistence-M | Bus-Id Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |

| Fan Temp Perf Pwr:Usage/Cap | Memory-Usage | GPU-Util Compute M. |

| | | MIG M. |

|=========================================+======================+======================|

| 0 NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 ... Off | 00000000:01:00.0 Off | N/A |

| N/A 46C P0 25W / 80W | 8MiB / 8192MiB | 0% Default |

| | | N/A |

+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+ 

It seems that CUDA is installed but when I run this
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt
print("TensorFlow built with CUDA:", tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
print("Num GPUs Available:", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

It returns 0 GPUs.

Does nvidia-settings/prime profiles  show "performance" selected, or something else?  How are you accessing the machine (local terminal, ssh, etc.)? I have installed the graphics-drivers Nvidia 555 driver directly (sudo apt install nvidia-driver-555) after purging all packages with "nvidia" in the name.

Did you restart your PC after install driver?

As previously Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 user, 24.04 makes me glad. In my opinion, thanks to current AI hype NVIDIA makes peace with Linux users at last. The thing is, in previous releases it took at least a day of time of me to be able to use CUDNN, but here in 24.04 I just followed these steps and it's done!
But first it is needed to mention that,

My laptop is Lenovo Thinkpad with PRX Quadro A4500 Laptop GPU.
I did not let the Ubuntu find the driver and download through App Center.

And the steps are :

Download the driver deb from datacenter by picking your GPU:
https://developer.nvidia.com/datacenter-driver-downloads

Install driver with following the instructions in download page:
For my GPU this was the instructions for reference :
 wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/nvidia-driver/565.57.01/local_installers/nvidia-driver-local-repo-ubuntu2404-565.57.01_1.0-1_amd64.deb

 sudo dpkg -i nvidia-driver-local-repo-ubuntu2404-565.57.01_1.0-1_amd64.deb

 sudo cp /var/nvidia-driver-local-repo-ubuntu2404-565.57.01/nvidia-driver-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/

 sudo apt-get update


At this step we can automatically install the CUDA as well with this :
sudo apt-get install -y cuda-drivers-565



You can verify your installation from bash using this :
nvidia-smi

You should see something like this with driver details on top-left and Cuda version on top-right:


Now we only need to install CUDNN :
https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn-downloads
 wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cudnn/9.5.1/local_installers/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2404-9.5.1_1.0-1_amd64.deb

 sudo dpkg -i cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2404-9.5.1_1.0-1_amd64.deb

 sudo cp /var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2404-9.5.1/cudnn-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/

 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get -y install cudnn


After these installations, I tested it in a Jupyter Notebook with these commands:
!pip install torch

import torch

if torch.cuda.is_available():

   print("CUDA is available! PyTorch can use the GPU.")
   print(f"Device count: {torch.cuda.device_count()}")
   print(f"Device name: {torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)}")
else:

   print("CUDA is not available. PyTorch cannot use the GPU.")



And you should see this response :

CUDA is available! PyTorch can use the GPU.


Device count: 1


Device name: NVIDIA RTX A4500 Laptop GPU

Hope this helps!
